# WriteConsole and ReadConsole Example - Doesn't read and write successfully

Tags: c, winapi

I have written the following program to print a message to the user and also get a password from it. Then I wanted to check and to verify the input password with my preferred password. Finally, I wanted to show a message to the user. However, my program doesn't work. It prints garbage characters to the user or when I give it input, it shows the wrong message. I think I have defined variables incorrectly, however, I don't know what is the best way to work with these APIs.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void PasswordCheck()
{
    char message_console[MAX_PATH];
    char key_accepted[MAX_PATH];
    char bad_key[MAX_PATH];
    char password_store[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD chars_read;

    strcpy(message_console, "Enter password for this malware: ");
    WriteConsoleA(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), message_console, sizeof(message_console), NULL, NULL);
    ReadConsoleA(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), password_store, MAX_PATH, &chars_read, NULL);
    
    if (!strcmp(password_store, "password"))
    {
        strcpy(key_accepted, "Key Accepted");
        WriteConsoleA(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), key_accepted, sizeof(key_accepted), NULL, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(bad_key, "Bad key");
        WriteConsoleA(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), bad_key, sizeof(bad_key), NULL, NULL);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    PasswordCheck();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrong lengths are sent and expected from the current code:

- Use `strlen()` not `sizeof()` to determine string length.  `sizeof()` returns the size of the arrays (`MAX_PATH`), so the garbage is from the rest of the array.
- If you check the value in `chars_read`, you'll see that `ReadConsole` is also returning the carriage return and linefeed (`\r\n`).
- `strncmp()` should be used as the return from `ReadConsole` isn't null-terminated.
  This code works:

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void PasswordCheck() {
    char message_console[MAX_PATH];
    char key_accepted[MAX_PATH];
    char bad_key[MAX_PATH];
    char password_store[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD chars_read;

    strcpy(message_console, "Enter password for this malware: ");
    WriteConsoleA(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), message_console, strlen(message_console), NULL, NULL);
    ReadConsoleA(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), password_store, MAX_PATH, &chars_read, NULL);
    if (!strncmp(password_store, "password\r\n",chars_read)) {
        strcpy(key_accepted, "Key Accepted");
        WriteConsoleA(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), key_accepted, strlen(key_accepted), NULL, NULL);
    } else {
        strcpy(bad_key, "Bad key");
        WriteConsoleA(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), bad_key, strlen(bad_key), NULL, NULL);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    PasswordCheck();
    return 0;
}
```

```
C:\>test
Enter password for this malware: password
Key Accepted
C:\>test
Enter password for this malware: blah
Bad key
```